# Assign content to cell array depending on index

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, vectorization

I would like to assign to each element of a cell array, a content depending on the cell index.

Example: a string containing the index of the cell

A way to do this using a for loop would be

```
for ind=1:10
   my_cell_array{ind}=['string' num2str(ind)];
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this using cellfun or anonymous function handles?

I have just learned these matlab tricks however i'm still not very good at using them, any suggestion would be very appreciated and helpful to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the following vectorized solution produces leading zeros, which may be desirable in some cases:

```
N = 10; % length
str = 'string'; % string
my_cell_array = cellstr(strcat(str, dec2base(1:N, 10)));
```

---

Since you want to know how to do it with `cellfun` (in this case [`arrayfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) is more suited): the following produces the same result as your code, without leading zeros:

```
my_cell_array = arrayfun(@(x) [str num2str(x)], 1:N, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Note however that `arrayfun` / `cellfun` are not vectorization. They have more or less the same performance as an explicit loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` with `%d` for the numbers. To separate it to cells, put a space at the end, and `strsplit`:

```
my_cell_array=strsplit(sprintf('string%d ',1:10))
```